# UserControl with definable content (How to created templated user control)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

A panel web control lets a developer put the panel on a page and define content that will appear inside the panel.

Is it possible to achieve similar functionality with a user control, where I define all my custom 'chrome' in the control, but am able to drop it on a page wherever I want and define the content inside on a per instance basis?

Comment: Don't believe this is possible with a `UserControl`-derived class. I think you have to implement the [`ITemplate` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx).

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the question; my link seems to be correct, though ;-)

Comment: Yes it is.  In fact ITemplate is a critical peice of the solution.

Comment: The thing I always looked for was an ASCX control that I could graphically design and when using this ASCX control, I still get the ability to define content. There was a reference somewhere on MSDN that this was planned, but it seems it never actually was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about a [Templated User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6.aspx). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1) Templated Controls as referred to by Uwe and Hanlet

2) jQuery UI library

3) ASP.NET 2.0 Web Parts

It's really tricky to implement no matter which way you go.

Answer (score 1):

As Hanlet Escaño pointed out, this is complete possible to do.  I'll show:

This is the user control markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TemplatedUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Templated_User_Control.TemplatedUserControl" %>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plContent" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Foot</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the user control code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Templated_User_Control
{
    public partial class TemplatedUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private ITemplate content_m = null;

        [TemplateContainer(typeof(ContentContainer))]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public ITemplate Content
        {
            get
            {
                return content_m;
            }
            set
            {
                content_m = value;
            }
        }

        void Page_Init()
        {
            if (content_m != null)
            {
                ContentContainer container = new ContentContainer();

                //This is the real magic.  Take the contents, and put it in our ContentContainer object, then
                //add the ContentContainer object as a child control of the placeholder so it renders inside the user control
                content_m.InstantiateIn(container);
                this.plContent.Controls.Add(container);
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
        public class ContentContainer : Control, INamingContainer {}
    }
}
```

This is the page markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Templated_User_Control.Default" %>
<%@ Register src="TemplatedUserControl.ascx" tagname="TemplatedUserControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:TemplatedUserControl ID="TemplatedUserControl1" runat="server">
            <Content>
                Template user control test.<br />
                <asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server">this is a test!</asp:Literal><br />
                abc 123!
            </Content>
        </uc1:TemplatedUserControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely possible.

Here is a [great example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/panelcurvecontainer.aspx) where a developer overrides an existing control (I chose an article with a Panel, since you used it as an example) and still allows content within.

The article is good, but you may find the sample code even more helpful.

Comment: He is asking for a `UserControl`, isn't he?